# Command window answer format

Tags: matlab, format

I am trying to get an answer to my system of equation. However, I can only get integer ratio value(xxx/yyy) instead of real number value(xx.xxx).
I tried to apply `format short` or `format long`, but it doesn't work at all.

```
format long
syms f12x f12y f23x f23y f34x f34y f14 t12
eqn1 = f34x + (2.86/32.17)*7850 ==0;
eqn2 = f14-f34y == 0;
eqn3 = f23x - f34x + (3.40/32.17)*7820 == 0;
eqn4 = f34y -f23y - (3.40/32.17)*4876 == 0;
eqn5 = (f23y*4.5+f34y*7.5)*cos(10.1821*pi/180)-(f23x*4.5+f34x*7.5)*sin(10.1821*pi/180)+0.108*7670 ==0;
eqn6 = f12x == f23x;
eqn7 = f23y == f12y;
eqn8 = f23y*3*cos(pi/4)+f23x*3*sin(pi/4)+t12 == 0;
sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5, eqn6, eqn7, eqn8],[f12x, f12y, f23x, f23y, f34x, f34y, f14, t12])
format long
f12xSol = round(sol.f12x*100)/100
f12ySol = round(sol.f12y*100)/100
f23xSol = round(sol.f23x*100)/100
f23ySol = round(sol.f23y*100)/100
f34xSol = round(sol.f34x*100)/100
f34ySol = round(sol.f34y*100)/100
f14Sol = round(sol.f14*100)/100
t12Sol = round(sol.t12*100)/100
```

This is the system of equation I made, and the command window output is

```
sol = 

  struct with fields:

    f12x: [1×1 sym]
    f12y: [1×1 sym]
    f23x: [1×1 sym]
    f23y: [1×1 sym]
    f34x: [1×1 sym]
    f34y: [1×1 sym]
     f14: [1×1 sym]
     t12: [1×1 sym]


f12xSol =

-152437/100


f12ySol =

-57323/100

*shortened* 


t12Sol =

111242/25
```

Can you teach me how to solve this problem? Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have symbolic answers, instead of numeric ones, so they are printed in whatever MATLAB thinks is the best way of representing them.

If you want to convert them to a number (and maybe loose a bit of precision), simply do

`double(f12xSol)`

and it will be converted to a double numerical value.

Comment: Thank you. I applied as ```f12xSol = double(sol.f12x)```, however it gives me exponential value,```-1.524370531551134e+03```. But I hope it would be better if I can get -1524.37. Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: `-1.524370531551134e+03` is the same as `-1524.37`, it's just how MATLAB displays nurmerical values. Check out the [`format` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) to change how MATLAB displays numbers.

Comment: @JaehoSong its the same number. try `format long g` and then checking its value again.

Comment: @JaehoSong consider accepting the question as valid